# jQuery: no logro cambiar atributos CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

El propósito del código es cambiar a la siguiente clase CSS mediante jQuery:

Clase CSS:

```css
.linkdestacacursos {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Importo la librería jQuery de la siguiente manera: https://code.jquery.com/

> *uncompressed . copio y pego debajo del CSS*:
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js">
> ```

Funciones jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  document
    .getElementById("cursos")
    .addEventListener("click", resaltarcursos, false);
  document
    .getElementById("informacion")
    .addEventListener("click", realtarejemplos, false);
});

function resaltarcursos() {
  $(".cursos").toggleClass("linkdestacacursos");
}

function resaltarejemplos() {}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para mejorar el formato de tu código. No logro reproducir el problema; ¿qué tienes en el html? Agrega un [mcve].

Comment: en el html tengo enlaces para resaltar PJ: 
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="cursos">
Google
</a><br>

Comment: Te falta el id...

Comment: Por qué usar `document.getElementById("cursos").addEventListener("click")` (que es vanilla Javascript) y no `$("#cursos").click( ... )`? Estas importando jQuery pero no lo estas usando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta lo que mencionas, cito:

> El propósito del código es cambiar a la siguiente clase CSS mediante jQuery

Además, de este:

```js
function resaltarcursos() {
  $(".cursos").toggleClass("linkdestacacursos");
}
```

Se entiende que lo que deseas hacer es alternar entre colocar la clase `.linkdestacacursos` y quitarla mediante el método `.toggleClass()` de **jQuery**.

#### Aclaratoria

Pero, antes hay que hacer una pequeña aclaratoria y se relaciona con las siguientes líneas, cito:

> ```js
> $(document).ready(function () {
>   document
>     .getElementById("cursos")
>     .addEventListener("click", resaltarcursos, false);
>   document
>     .getElementById("informacion")
>     .addEventListener("click", realtarejemplos, false);
> });
> ```

Aquí estás utilizando una combinación de *Vanilla JS* con jQuery, pero si deseas utilizar únicamente la segunda podrías escribirlo así:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#cursos").on("click", resaltarcursos);
  $("#informacion").on("click", resaltarejemplos);
});
```

Por otra parte, [**jQuery**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) recomienda utilizar a partir de la **versión 3.0** las siguientes líneas:

```js
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

En lugar de esta:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

Porque esta última ha sido declarada obsoleta.

#### Ver ejemplo completo

Ahora vamos a correr el ejemplo completo. Pero, en esta oportunidad, agregaremos los HTML faltante para completarlo:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#cursos").on("click", resaltarcursos);
});

function resaltarcursos() {
  $(".cursos").toggleClass("linkdestacacursos");
}
```

```css
.linkdestacacursos {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.cursos {
  transition: 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="cursos" class="cursos">Cursos</a>
<a href="#" id="informacion">Información</a>
```

La siguiente línea se omite en el ejemplo anterior:

```js
$("#informacion").on("click", resaltarejemplos);
```

Que ejecuta la siguiente función:

```js
function resaltarejemplos() {}
```

Porque no hay nada que hacer allí, dado que la función no realiza ninguna acción.